# UML Class diagram Multiple TabPages

Tags: c#, uml, tabcontrol, class-diagram, tabpage

I am currently working on a C# Windows Froms project thar requires the use of TabControll and multiple TabPAges with each of them having several buttons, labels and text boxes.

since i've now reached the class diagram phase of the project i discovered that i have no idea how to represent it in the class diagram.

lets say i have a form called MainForm that has 4 tabpages named tab_page1-tab_page4, with each having their own buttons that do different things, how am is uposed to show it in my UML class diagram?

thank you for your time

Comment: You should try Google. There are tons of scaffolds for wireframes.

Comment: It's better to post what you tried and ask a specific question about them.

Comment: I've tried searching in google but could not find a result about it sadly. @ThomasKilian

Comment: I my idea, there is **Aggregation Relationship** between `MainForm` and other `tabpage`s.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest representation via shared aggregations, e.g. the TabPage being aggregated into TabControl which is aggregated into Form etc. If you want to get really into it you could illustrate the inheritance hierarchy of each of the controls themselves as well, but it depends on what your purpose is really. Simplest way probably the best.